# What are the diffrences between `tput cols`, `tput lines` and `stty size`?

Tags: terminal

Are there differences between `tput cols`, `tput lines` and `stty size` written in this way (apart that `stty size` returns all in one string)?

Is one more portable or more reliable than the other?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment I am asking myself the same question.

What I see on linux:

- tput depends on ncurses
- stty depends on coreutils and coreutils depends on ncurses

IMHO tput is more basic and portable.